# How to do reverse slicing in python?

Tags: python, slice

Say I have `lst = [1, 2, 3]` and I want to access the last two elements in reverse order, as in `[3, 2]`

How do I do that using slicing?

Comment: Why not just reverse a forward slice: `reversed(lst[-2:])`. Doing it in a slice is non-intuitive: `lst[:0:-1]`

Answer (score 5):

Simply put bounds into your slice:

```
>>> [1,2,3][-1:-3:-1]
[3, 2]
```

In the slice `-1:-3:-1`:

- the first element is the position of where we want to start (`-1`);
- the second is where we wish to stop (non-inclusive);
- and the third is the direction (or skip) (backwards).

Answer (score 1):

- [-2::] will return the last two elements
- [::-1] will reverse it

So the answer will be:

```
lst[-2::][::-1]
```

I checked @donkopotamus's answer and it is actually the best answer

Answer (score 1):

Get the last two elements!

And then reverse it!

```
>>> lst
[1, 2, 3]
>>> lst[-2:][::-1]
[3, 2]
```